# What is the difference between 'last' and 'least'?

Tags: differences, quotes

What is the difference between 'last' and 'least'? Is least a superlative of last?

Comment: You need to show signs of your own research, and a case where the difference is not obvious.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary?

Comment: No. It's the superlative of _little_. _Little, less, least_. _Last_ is not a grammatical superlative; it's more of a limit point ordinal number, like _first_, which also uses the -st suffix: _first, second, third, ..., last._

Comment: @John, I'd personally say it is a grammatical superlative. The comparative is _latter_, and there is no positive (except semi-suppletively _late_).

Comment: Nah, I'm sure that's the historical derivation, but I don't think _late, latter, last_ is productive for most English speakers any more. It certainly isn't for me. And how about _first_? Not to mention _Oktoberfee, Oktoberfetter, Oktoberfest_.

Comment: My "productive" comparatives are *little, littler, littlest*. The fact that *less* and *least* can be used in such contexts seems almost incidental to me - a bit like saying *almighty* is another alternative superlative for the regular/productive set *mighty, mightier, mightiest*.

Comment: The letter 'e'!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thet are two different words.
**last** (a determiner)=happening or coming after all other similar things or people. example: "He was the **last** person to leave." "I missed the **last** bus."
**least** (an adverb)= to the smallest degree. example: I chose the **least** expensive dress and bought it. Least is the superlative form of "**Little"**
It's
**little** = positive form
     **less** = comparative form
     **least** = superlative form